# Como inserir, como uma nova coluna, os nomes em um vetor no R?

Tags: data.frame, r

Tenho um vetor, chamado *istrain*, com nomes:

```
istrain = c("carri", "challeng", ...)
```

E pretendo transformá-los em colunas de um *dataframe, testSparse,* que contém frequências de ocorrência de palavras em comentários, algo como:

```
testSparse$cool = c(0,0,0,0,13,252,...)
testSparse$court= c(0,0,12,143,53,...)
```

o *dataframe testSparse*, depois da operação, ficaria com as colunas:

```
testSparse$carri = c(0,0,0,0,0,...)
testSparse$challeng = c(0,0,0,0,0,...)
```

O modo manual é bem demorado, visto que o vetor de novas colunas possui mais de 100 ocorrências, alguém já fez ou conhece algum pacote que faça algo parecido, mas de modo mais rápido?

Obs.: linguagem R, são *dataframes* de pré-processamento para árvores de decisão para text mining, e o vetor de novas colunas é a diferença entre os corpus finais de treino e de teste, e a função ocasionada por essas modificações busca ser mais genérica, para poder ser aplicada a novas bases de textos, utilizando-se a mesma árvore de decisão para verificar se o comentário é ofensivo ou não, mas a nova base de texto possui palavras que não foram tratadas anteriormente, e não possui algumas que já existem. a frequência das novas palavras, portanto, deve ser 0, e com estas adicionadasposso passar a nova base e predizer caso seja um comentário ofensivo ou não, dentre várias classes de *"ofensividade".*

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?

se entendi sua duvida você tem o seguinte:

uma lista de nomes:

```
istrain = c("carri", "challeng")
```

e um data.frame chamado testSparse que eu construi da seguinte forma:

```
cool = c(0,0,0,0,13,252)
court= c(0,0,12,143,53,0)
testSparse <- data.frame(cool,court)
```

que visualmente fica assim:

```
testSparse
> testSparse
cool court
1    0     0
2    0     0
3    0    12
4    0   143
5   13    53
6  252     0
```

para renomear as colunas de um data.frame podemos utilizar a função colnames ela aceita a alteração das colunas atraves de uma lista veja só:

```
colnames(testSparse)<-istrain
testSparse

> testSparse
carri challeng
1     0        0
2     0        0
3     0       12
4     0      143
5    13       53
6   252        0
```

Espero ter ajudado!